# How To Display Date (/Time/Author) In pages?

Tags: pages

I'm trying to search for a way to display the published date of a page, but I can't seem to find one. Maybe because the "PAGE" word is very generic.

But what I'm looking for is a way to display date in a page. Displaying the date (and author and time) is pretty easy with posts because they're automatically built within the theme.

I would appreciate any help on this.

SAMPLE [POST (WITH DATE)](http://randomscribbler.com/2016/04/18/sample-post/) - date at the bottom of the post, below the sharing buttons.

SAMPLE [PAGE (NO DATE)](http://randomscribbler.com/sample-page-2/)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Posts and pages are very similar in WP (they are both _post types_), their templating pretty much nearly identical.

Comment: @Rarst Hi. Thanks for the response. Updated the query with links at the bottom. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has some nifty functions which do this for you. You'll need some experiences with HTML, CSS, PHP to style the output and understand what these functions do but the functions you're looking for are:

- [`the_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) which displays the post date.
- [`the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author) which displays the author of the post.

In your theme will most likely be a `page.php` template where you can add these on pages into [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) like so:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
        <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning my ways around Wordpress so this would be something that I would go back to once I get the hang of things.

Comment: I finally tested it on my site and it worked! Thank you :)